# Coordinate Systems vs Reference Frames vs States of Motion

Tags: special-relativity, symmetry, gauge-invariance

This is a broad conceptual question. I am really trying to understand symmetry as deeply as possible. Please let that guide your responses.

In particular, I'm looking for help finding clarity on the issue of reference frames vs coordinate systems vs states of motion.

The basic idea behind symmetry in theoretical physics seems to be that the true 'facts of the universe' are those patterns/equations which do not encode anything about the conventions we are using to describe them. This is precisely what makes them facts of nature, rather than artifacts of our parochial points of view.

Special Relativity seems to be an application of this principle. In that context, e.g. the size of the spacetime interval between two events in spacetime is a fact, i.e. it holds true for all observers. This is in contrast to the spatial and temporal components of that interval, which are different for different observers and therefore are not 'facts' in the more robust sense of the word.

To help myself understand symmetries such as these, I often think of the unit circle. In this 'toy model', the radius of the circle stands in for a fact of nature, in that it is the same no matter what angle you orient your x, y axes. But as you rotate the axes, the x and y components change. In fact, they MUST change in order that the fact of the radius will remain a true fact.

There is of course a bit more to this than analogy, since Lorentz transformations can be understood as rotations not on a unit circle but on a unit hyperbola.

This is where my confusion finally enters in. In the unit circle case, I am just describing the circle using different coordinate systems, which are rotated relative to each other. It stands to reason (I think) that the radius cannot depend on what is ultimately an arbitrary convention.

However, for the Lorentz transformation case, the change of coordinate system (which 'mixes' the space and time components into each other) models a change in uniform velocity.

So my question is this: Is this to say that our (uniform) states of motion are not more real than our coordinate system conventions? I suppose perhaps this is the point of Galileo and Einstein insisting that 'motion is relative'? So that the difference between my own experience 'standing still' and that of someone traveling at great speed on an airplane is no more real - no more factual - than the difference between someone analyzing a circle with a coordinate system rotated relative to the one I'm using?

To blow the question open even more, is this the general sense of all symmetries? That the patterns we discern in nature can be said to arise from (and give rise to) the existence of certain facts? I think in particular of local gauge symmetry, which when postulated implies the existence of the EM potential, i.e. the whole 'symmetries give rise to interactions' argument.

It seems to me that the gauge argument implies that the following two facts imply each other:

a) There is an electromagnetic force.

b) The path of minimal action is the same regardless of where we set the zero point of phase angle from point to point.

I am deeply confused about why it should be that real forces should arise from a point about the choices we make to describe reality.

Comment: I might be wrong , but I suspect you are confusing symmetry with invariant. Symmetry is something that looks the same in a given coordinate system, an invariant is something that has the same value in all coordinate systems